# Comparar fechas, cronjobs y Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenos días estoy haciendo con cronjobs unas notificaciones, basadas en si una fecha coincide. Pero tengo registros que la fecha de un año ya a pasado pero no se a enviado el mail y no se le enviara por que la fecha ya nunca coincidira.

¿Se puede hacer de alguna forma, enviar ese email a esas fechas pasadas?

```
$fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d");
$envio_email = \DB::table('equipos')->where('fecha_revision', $fecha_actual)->select('equipos.*')->where('estado_email', 0)->get();

foreach($envio_email as $enviando){
  $id = $enviando->id;
  $sacaCliente = \DB::table('clientes')->where('id', $enviando->cliente_id)->select('clientes.*')->first();
  $asunto = "⚠ Revisión anual equipo | Nº de referencia $enviando->serie";


   $tt = DB::table('equipos')
     ->where('id', $id)
      ->update([
         'estado_email' => 1
        ]);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia la siguiente linea:

```php
$envio_email = \DB::table('equipos')->where('fecha_revision', '<=', $fecha_actual)->select('equipos.*')->where('estado_email', 0)->get();
```

De esta forma cogera los emails que tengan la fecha_revision anterior o igual a la $fecha_actual (La cual supongo es hoy).

Todo esto esta explicado en la documentacion oficial de laravel:
[Documentacion oficial Laravel, apartado Where de las Querys](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto!!!

Comment: como hizo para que le funcionara las notificaciones mediante cronjobs, soy nueva en eso y no entiendo mucho.

Comment: Basándome en el código, supongo que habrá hecho un script que manda un email, y un cronjob ejecuta ese script cada x tiempo...